# ASP.NET Confirm Message without OnClientClick/Button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

is it possible to raise a confirmation message with yes/no from code behind, without any use of client click?

My problem setup:

1. A row is going to be deleted from a datagrid
2. delete function checks if the selected row has dependencies
3. if the row has children (dependencies) raise a message if the user wants to keep going with the delete process, if not cancel the function.

I can't check the dependencies beforehand to set the javascript confirm on the delete button (performance would die [there are other database issues...]).

I need to raise the message from the function with an return value which the code behind can use. Is there any native way to do this?

Small sample:

```
Private Sub Delete(ByVal sender As Object, Optional ByVal e As System.EventArgs = Nothing)

   //Do check for dependencies...
   If intDependencyCounter > 0 Then

      //This is where i need my message to be shown
      Dim blUserInput As Boolean = True/False //depends on user input

      If blUserInput = False Then

         //Cancel function...

      Else

         //Keep going with function...

      EndIf

   EndIf

End Sub
```

Hope someone can give me an idea how to solve this.

Regards,
Megajin

Comment: you can fire javascript from codebehind but not sure either you can get back the result (yes/no) back to code

Comment: I know that it is possible through Scriptmanager. And with the use of a hidden field I could get the value. But for that to work a postback would be necessary or an ajax call. Which I can not use in this kind of situation =(.

Comment: that's why i said not sure you can get back the result

Comment: If you want the user to press delete, then postback, and check whether confirmation is required, and then only process the delete when the user confirms, then you're going to need a second postback or an ajax call after the confirmation is given. Whether you display the confirmation UI as a javascript yes/no box or using some other thing (e.g. another Panel that you enable) doesn't really matter. Either is possible - you can inject the javascript to trigger the confirm box using ScriptManager as mentioned above, or make a hidden panel visible. Either way you would need a 2nd call to the server

Comment: You need round trip to the server. Ajax would be your best bet here to avoid sending and receiving more data than needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've got a new idea how to solve this. If it works I will share it here.